# Flutter - OneSignal setNotificationOpenedHandler not working on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

I used OneSignal to receive notifications from the server. In Android, when I click on a notification, the function setNotificationOpenedHandler fire and redirect to the detail screen. But in iOS, it doesn't work. My iOS device runs on iOS 15+.

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((openedResult) {
    //not working on iOS
    AdditionalNotificationModel additionalNotificationModel =
        AdditionalNotificationModel.fromJson(openedResult.notification.additionalData ?? {});
    FunctionUtils.redirectNotification(additionalNotificationModel);
    readNotification( additionalNotificationModel);
  });
```

Comment: Looks like bug: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/540